# Search for an integer ending in '9' using SQL

Tags: sql, informix

As part of a query I need to search for a nine digit number where the last number is 9.

How would I do such a query?

Comment: Modular arithmetic will do

Comment: is it mysql or sql server?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left

Comment: I am not familiar with how this works - can you help me?

Comment: it is an informix server - quite old

Comment: Is your column an int or a varchar

Comment: my column is an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MOD for % in informix 
and between for 9 digits

```
select colname 
from tablename 
where 
    MOD(colname, 10) = 9
and colname between 100000000 and 999999999
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select colname from tablename where colname%10 = 9
```

Comment: An illegal character has been found in the statement.

Comment: if you tag the appropriate database, it can be resolved.

Comment: thanks - sorry this is my first ever question - I am so impressed with how stackexchange works!

Comment: you should replace `%` with the appropriate `modulo` operator in informix.

Answer (score 0):

Where clause:

```
Where n % 10 = 9
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this

The len function makes sure the length of what you are looking for is 9 characters

```
Select * from table where column like '%9' and len(column) = 9
```

Comment: Wildcard matching may not be used with non-character types.

Comment: FOR MySQL function is LENGTH.

Comment: It's not a MySQL database.